# How to join 3 tables in sql with or condition

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:
table1

- inner join with table2; or:
- inner join with table3

The query:

```
select table1.x
from table1 right outer join
     table2
     on table1.x = table2.x right outer join
     table3
     on table1.x = table3.x
```

but I can only see x values that are in both table2 and table3

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`, not `right join`, along with an appropriate filter condition:

```
select table1.x
from table1 left join
     table2
     on table1.x = table2.x left join
     table3
     on table1.x = table3.x
where table2.x is not null or table3.x is not null;
```

You might consider writing this using `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.x = t1.x) or
      exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.x = t1.x);
```

That seems like a more natural way to implement your logic -- and you won't get duplicates when `x` is duplicated in `table2` or `table3`.